# Checking abilities in CanCan on a namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Given the following example from the CanCan wiki,

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace

How would I do a **can?** check within a view for the namespaced *article* controller.
For the purpose of this, imagine the ability.rb file states the current user.role is able to view an article, and the admin_ability.rb states the user can create an article

```
<% if can? :read, Articles %>
  I can view an article
<% end %>


<% if can? :create, Articles %>
  I can create an article
<% end %>
```

I don't know how to get the latter to work. It would be neat if I could specify the namespace on it perhaps such as

```
<% if admin::can? :create, Articles %>
```

But I am not sure what the syntax would be if that were possible.

Comment: Duplicate of [Authorizing Namespaced and Nested controllers using CanCan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334367/authorizing-namespaced-and-nested-controllers-using-cancan).  Only question 12334367 has the correct answer to this common question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Marc's suggestion will work. Checkout this wiki from Ryan. 
    https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<% if can? :create, Admin::Articles %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will let you know if it works when I get back to that project (sometime!)